# Как получить символ строки?

Tags: c++, строки

С числами всё понятно, там младший разряд можно получить с помощью деления по модулю 10: `2498 % 10 = 8`.

А как подобное проделать со строковой переменной? Ведь `stackoverflow % 10` не будет равно `w`.

Comment: Оператор [] в помощь...

Comment: Предлагаете решить массивом? Но как?

Comment: Не массивом, а оператором доступа по индексу. Например как тут http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/

Не нравятся скобочки - str.at(0) и т.п.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

переменные string в отличие от int, например, в своей основе имеют массив. 
Для выделения отдельных букв из слова можно обращаться к соответствующему номеру элемента.
Например, если речь идёт о c++, то:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string str = "stackoverflow";
    std::cout << str[10] << std::endl; // Вывод 10го символа;
    return 0;
}
```

Проверить работоспособность этой программы можно онлайн: http://rextester.com/live/GFYQR85775

Comment: Кажется разобрался..

Answer (score 2):

Если вы о переменной типа std::string, то у него есть оператор **[]**, для доступа к символам по заданной позиции. Например,

```
std::string s("abcd");
```

s[2] возвратит символ 'c'