# как сделать проверку на строку?

Tags: c++

вот пример того что я хочу узнать :

есть файл txt в котором лежит абослютно любой текст.
Мне нужно сделать проверку на то сколько в нем уникальных букв и количество встречаемыъ букв.

пример:

Это вывод в консоль:

```
Unique: [ '"', ''', ',', '-', '.', ':', ';', '?' ]
Matches in text:
    " = 4 matches
    ' = 12 matches
    , = 35 matches
    - = 2 matches
    . = 47 matches
    : = 3 matches
    ; = 2 matches
    ? = 2 matches
```

это все с помощью:

```
bool TextHandler::isSpecial(char symbol) {
    bool special = false;

    if ( ( symbol > ' ' && symbol < '0' ) || ( symbol > '9' && symbol < 'A' ) ) {
        special = true;
    }
    if ( ( symbol > 'Z' && symbol < 'a' ) || ( symbol > 'z' && symbol <= '~' ) ) {
        special = true;
    }
    return special;
}
```

проверка на спецсимволы.

**как сделать примерно также,только проверять строку на то содержит ли она текст?**

типо :

```
bool TextHandler::isWord(std::string word) {
     return //some code
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, чего вы хотите и зачем, строка будет строкой, а вот ее содержимое...?

Comment: как проверить содержимое строки?

Comment: Проверить состоит ли строка только из букв?

Comment: да,есть в строке какой-то набор символов

Comment: [Как получить символ строки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726989) + [Как узнать, является ли символ буквенным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/926168)